# Linq to SQL GroupBy several fields

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the SQL and trying to convert ti to Linq query. I need to group records by several fields, how to do that in Linq?

```
var statistic = DataAccess.Instance.Statistics.Where(
p =>
    p.DateStamp >= minDate &&
    p.DateStamp <= DateTime.UtcNow && p.UserId == userId &&
    p.Url.Contains(url)
    ).
    GroupBy(p=>p.PageTitle //How to group by second(Url) field? 


 SELECT PageTitle
             , Url
             , Count(*) As [Count]
          FROM Statistic
         WHERE URL like @url
         AND DateSpan BETWEEN @dateRange1 AND @dateRange2
         AND UserId = @UserId
         GROUP BY PageTitle, Url
         ORDER BY Count(*) DESC, Url;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group By Multiple Columns - LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by an anonymous type:

```
.GroupBy(p => new { p.PageTitle, p.Url })
```