# Linq - SQL passing parameters into GroupBy()

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Using a linq query, how can i pass parameters into the groupby function? Depend on user selection, it will be grouped differently

```
 var query = (from to in OrderQuery
                     group to by to.FromDateUtc into groupedDate
                     let grouped = groupedDate.GroupBy(o => o.Name)
```

I would like to pass different groupby values. Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `SELECT * FROM <TableName> GROUP BY <Column1>,<Column2>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need different queries for this.  The same goes for building up different `WHERE` or `Where(...)` clauses based on user selection:

```
var query = OrderQuery;
if (userSelection == "GroupByName") {
    query = from to in query
            group to by to.FromDateUtc into groupedDate
            let grouped = groupedDate.GroupBy(o => o.Name);
}
else if (userSelection == "GroupBySomethingElse") {
    query = from to in query
            group to by to.FromDateUtc into groupedDate
            let grouped = groupedDate.GroupBy(o => o.SomethingElse);
}
```

You'll want to prepare as much common logic as possible before you apply the grouping to `query`.  Because LINQ uses deferred execution you can modify `query` as much as you need before enumerating the result and you will not incur a performance hit.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting.. This is just 10% of my query. Seems like i need to copy and paste a whole lot :(

Comment: @overule Well, hopefully not. The only parts you'd need to copy & paste would be those that deal with the *differences* in how you're grouping. As I mentioned, you should set up `query` to contain any joins, filtering, sorting before you conditionally apply grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> GROUP BY <Column1>,<Column2>
```

Then, take a look at this post

[Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)