# Linq query with count (extension method)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I expect a very simple solution, but I can't for the life of me figure this out...

I am trying to create the LINQ equivalent of this:

```
SELECT Group, COUNT(*) as GroupCount
FROM table1
WHERE Valid > 0
GROUP BY Group, Project
```

I have this so far:

```
var model = _db.table1
    .Where(r => r.Valid > 0)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.GROUP, r.Project})
    .Select(r => new{ r.GROUP, GroupCount = r.count()};
```

What is wrong with my query? Visual studio throws and error stating that:

> System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'GROUP' and no extension method 'GROUP' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

EDIT: Just a note: The above error is given for `r.Group` in the `Select` clause.

It also throws an error stating that the `count` extension method doesn't exist, but I've seen other examples done this way. Maybe I was looking at an example from an old version of LINQ?

EDIT2: Some example data

```
GroupName    ProjectID    Step    Other Info...
-----------------------------------------------
GroupA     |     1      |   1   | ..............
GroupA     |     1      |   2   |..............
GroupA     |     3      |   1   | ..............
GroupB     |     4      |   1   | ..............
GroupB     |     5      |   1   | ..............
GroupC     |     6      |   1   |..............
```

Desired result:

```
 GroupName    Group Count
--------------------------- 
GroupA      |     2
GroupB      |     2
GroupC      |     1
```

Comment: `.count` should be `.Count()`, it's case sensitive...

Comment: DOH! That issue is fixed. Thanks

Comment: You probably want to select the key in the group: `.Select(r => new{ r.GROUP, GroupCount = r.count()};` should probably be `.Select(r => new{ r.Key, GroupCount = r.Count()};`

Comment: I did not know about the `Key` keyword. It seems like that creates a key based on the items in the `GroupBy` clause. Are these values concatenated? What if I really only want to show `Group`? Or is it a requirement to include `Key` in queries that use aggregate functions?

Comment: Well, you can use `r.Key.Group` if you only want to show `Group`. See my answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have following errors in the `.Select` statement:

- `.count` should be `.Count` (C# is case sensitive)
- `r.GROUP` should be `r.Key` or `r.Key.GROUP` (.GroupBy() returns an [IGrouping<TKey, TElement>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx))
- You forgot the last parenthesis in the Select method. (But maybe that was just a typo in the example)

Result:

```
var model = _db.table1
    .Where(r => r.Valid > 0)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.GROUP, r.Project })
    .Select(r => new { r.Key.GROUP, GroupCount = r.Count() });
```

---

**UPDATE:**

After the comments and question update; it looks like you are only grouping by group, so that would turn in to something like this to yield the output you requested:

```
var model = _db.table1
    .Where(r => r.Valid > 0)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.GROUP }) // First, group only on GROUP
    .Select(r => new 
    { 
        r.Key.GROUP, 
        // Second, group on unique ProjectId's
        GroupCount = r.GroupBy(g => g.Project).Count()
    });
```

Or simplified:

```
var model = _db.table1
    .Where(r => r.Valid > 0)
    .GroupBy(r => r.GROUP) // First, group only on GROUP
    .Select(r => new 
    { 
        Group = r.Key, 
        // Second, group on unique ProjectId's
        GroupCount = r.GroupBy(g => g.Project).Count() 
    });
```

As you asked in the comments, yes, you could say that the values are concatenated in the GroupBy clause. So `new { r.GROUP, r.Project }` would group all pairs with the same value.

Comment: This works, but seems to yield unexpected results. My intent is to gather the number of unique `Project` assigned to each unique `Group`. My `GroupCount` ends up being 1 for each row. I wonder if it has something to do with `r.Key.Group`...
EDIT: Looks like I should be using `r.Project.Count()` or `r.Key,Project.Count()`.

Comment: @Jeff I have tested with some mock-up data and it works for me, but maybe I am misunderstanding you. Can you give an example of the data you have and what the output should be?

Comment: I have added example data in the question.

Comment: @Jeff I have updated my answer, this will yield the output you have given.

Comment: I apologize as I submitted before I was able to add the Step column. Now you see, there can be multiple entries of a particular `ProjectID`, so it is necessary to also group by `ProJectID`.

Comment: @Jeff Ok, but the desired result makes no sense right now... there should be 4 rows in the result, right? And even with 4 rows, do you really get that result in your SQL query?

Comment: `GroupCount` should be the number of UNIQUE `ProjectID`. There should still be 3 rows as there are 3 unique `GroupName`.

Comment: @Jeff I think I understand what you want, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ queries are case-sensitive. You're trying to access `r.GROUP`, which probably doesn't exist. Use `r.Group` instead. Also change `r.count()` to `r.Count()`. Here's the corrected code:

```
var model = _db.table1
    .Where(r => r.Valid > 0)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.Group, r.Project})
    .Select(r => new{ r.Key, GroupCount = r.Count()};
```

Comment: @IronMan84 Doesn't it? Which one do you mean? I guess that if he replaces the references to `r.GROUP` with `r.Group` as I did in my example it will probably solve OP's problem

Comment: His group error is not because of case sensitivity. It's because he needs to use r.Key.

Comment: @IronMan84 oh, yes you're right. I missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing the Group By, you're creating a new anonymous type (not of the type you think it is). Thus, when you're doing the select statement, it has no idea what the heck GROUP is.

To mitigate this, follow the 2nd answer [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns).