# How to group the linq query by two id's

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

How can i use group by two id's; I have data like

```
empid: 1, usrid: 1, profid: 1
empid: 1, usrid: 1, profid: 2
empid: 2, usrid: 1, profid: 5
```

I have written query like

```
var query = (from i in data
         group i by new { i.empid, i.usrid} into g
         select new {                         
         profileid = g.Select(z=>z.profileid).ToArray()                         
         }).ToArray();
```

Now for the `empid:1` and `usrid:1` i want to get profile id as an array of `1,2`
and for `empid:2` and `usrid:1` i want to get `prof id` as `5`

But i am getting all the three values in each record like `1,2,5`

How can i get that using linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Comment: It must something in your data. There's nothing wrong with what you show. Maybe you can show a full running code snippet that displays the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @MitchWheat that Q&A shows how to group by multiple columns but that's not the problem here.

Comment: @GertArnold yah you are right now i get that thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to see what is going on when I do it in steps.

First group the data

```
var grouped = data.GroupBy(d => new { d.empid, d.userid });
```

Then select the results

```
var results = grouped.Select(g => g.Select(d => d.profid).ToArray());
```

Each `g` is a group keyed by a pair of `empid` and `userid`. That group is a collection of instances your class. So the above statement says to make an array of the `profid`s from each group (each `empid` `userid` pair). The results turn out to be

```
[1, 2]
[5]
```

That gets you the arrays you want, but you lose the keys that way. I don't know what you want to do with the results so that might be okay, but probably not. Either way the groups do contain the keys and the values you want.

Another way to approach the problem is to use a different overload of `GroupBy` to get just the `profid` as a value.

```
var grouped2 = data.GroupBy(d => new { d.empid, d.userid }, d => d.profid);
```

This will give you a group with a key being the pair of `empid` and `userid` and the collection being just the `profid`s. This is more likely to be closer to what you want.