# Select entire duplicate row from datatable with linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I can get it to return the single column, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to give me the entire row instead of just the column values.

Help!!

the fields it should return are, VDMList and Table.

```
var duplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("VMDList"))
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();


columns of DT Table, VDMList
output is
4  | 02,2
12 | 03,3
15 | 02,2
```

Comment: cau you show the output?

Comment: And can you also show us the table structure?

Comment: entire row-> on what criteria, some values will be missed

Comment: columns of DT Table, VDMList
output is
4  | 02,2
12 | 03,3
15 | 02,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following query will return `first` item in the `group` for rows with duplicate `VMDList`. Note that there is no criteria for selecting the `first` item. It can be any `random` row.

```
var duplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("VMDList"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

To return all rows that have duplicates, Use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
var allDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("VMDList"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I want it to return all the rows that have duplicates, not just the first one.

Comment: You need to use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx). Updated the answer

Comment: How can I do this if the duplicates have to be found based on a group of unique columns?

Comment: @b.g Check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161180/use-linq-to-find-duplicated-rows-with-list-of-specified-columns

Answer (score -1):

If the requirement is selecting the entire row rather than selecting a column, then modify the linq as follows:

```
var duplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
.Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("VMDList"))
.GroupBy(x => x)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.Select(g);
```

Where duplicates will be a group collection.