# Use LINQ to find duplicated rows (with list of specified columns)

Tags: c#, linq

I use the code below to get the duplicated rows for 3 columns: String, Date, Money. 
I wonder if there is any general method that I can input a dynamic List of column name in this LINQ to find duplicated rows?

```
DataTable allDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(dr => new
    { 
        Field1 = dr.Field<object>("String"), 
        Field2 = dr.Field<object>("Date"), 
        Field3 = dr.Field<object>("Money"), 
    })
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList().CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about with a custom  `ArrayEqualityComparer<T>` type (such as the one [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244729/412770)):

```
string[] colsToConsider = ...

var allDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(dr => colsToConsider.Select(dr.Field<object>)
                                                   .ToArray(),
                               new ArrayEqualityComparer<object>())       
                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                      .SelectMany(g => g)
                      .CopyToDataTable();
```

You can also consider using a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (and an associated dictionary-comparer) if you find the implicit use of array indices here hackish.

Comment: Incredible! It works like a charm. You must be a master. However, it takes me a while to realize that ArrayEqualityComparer isn't a built-in .NET library, it is custom created by other from the link that you provided.

Comment: Cheers. I've added the word "custom" to my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

while execute above code.

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly