# How to compare the each row in a list object and how to get the same data using linq or Angular

Tags: c#, linq

From Service, I will get the list of data. From the data I need to identify which all are same data and which are not. For Example,

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAAA | TEST 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4 | Test 5 | Test 6 | Test 7 |
| BBBBBB | TEST 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4 | Test 5 | Test 6 | Test 7 |
| CCCCCC | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| DDDDDD | Cell 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

From the above AAAAAA and BBBBBB has the same data but remaining CCCCCC and DDDDDD different data. When I get the list of data, I need to compare the other list of rows and need to get the Same configurations data like AAAAAA and BBBBBB rows having the same data and others having the different data in Angular or linq. Can you please let me know how to get it?

I didnt get idea how to do it. Can anyone please help us?

Comment: Using LINQ, you can groupby columnA and select other columns. Please see this link for getting duplicate rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161180/use-linq-to-find-duplicated-rows-with-list-of-specified-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can `GroupBy()` each row like:

```
var rows = data
    .GroupBy(x => new {
        ColumnB = x["Column B"],
        ColumnC = x["Column C"],
        ColumnD = x["Column D"],
        ColumnE = x["Column E"],
        ColumnF = x["Column F"],
        ColumnG = x["Column G"],
        ColumnH = x["Column H"]
    })
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1);
```