# Select multiple fields group by and sum

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-group

I want to do a query with linq (list of objects) and I really don't know how to do it, I can do the group and the sum but can't select rest of the fields.
Example:

```
ID  Value     Name   Category
1   5         Name1  Category1  
1   7         Name1  Category1
2   1         Name2  Category2
3   6         Name3  Category3
3   2         Name3  Category3
```

I want to group by ID, SUM by Value and return all fields like this.

```
ID  Value     Name   Category
1   12        Name1  Category1  
2   1         Name2  Category2
3   8         Name3  Category3
```

Comment: Do you have check ? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b  and your case: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: since all the fields seems unique for each ID, why don't you include them in the group as well.

Comment: Yes I can do that but I have more fields than that... :(

Comment: go through this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns
hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Updated :
If you're trying to avoid grouping for all the fields, you can group just by `Id`:

```
data.GroupBy(d => d.Id)
    .Select(
        g => new
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Value = g.Sum(s => s.Value),
            Name = g.First().Name,
            Category = g.First().Category 
        });
```

But this code assumes that for each `Id`, the same `Name` and `Category` apply. If so, you should consider normalizing as @Aron suggests. It would imply keeping `Id` and `Value` in one class and moving `Name`, `Category` (and whichever other fields would be the same for the same `Id`) to another class, while also having the `Id` for reference. The normalization process reduces data redundancy and dependency.

Comment: Yes I know it but just dont want to group all fields, would be a differnt way, I try with first() but then how to sum?

Comment: Yes I know what are you saying, I have my DB normalize, it is just a result of my query, but for each lines of my query I have repeat it values, and I want agroup them and sum the Value.

Answer (score 4):

```
void Main()
{
            //Me being lazy in init
    var foos = new []
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Value = 5},
        new Foo { Id = 1, Value = 7},
        new Foo { Id = 2, Value = 1},
        new Foo { Id = 3, Value = 6},
        new Foo { Id = 3, Value = 2},
    };
    foreach(var x in foos)
    {
        x.Name = "Name" + x.Id;
        x.Category = "Category" + x.Id;
    }
            //end init.

    var result = from x in foos
                group x.Value by new { x.Id, x.Name, x.Category}
                into g
                select new { g.Key.Id, g.Key.Name, g.Key.Category, Value = g.Sum()};
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Category {get;set;}   
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but I dont want to have in my group so many fields, I have more that 7.

Comment: @user2112420 Then you are going to have to normalise your class.

Comment: It is a result query I do from multiple table and create a object this type.

Comment: I just do my query from different tables, the result would be type an Object, with that query I have create a list of my objects, because in each row I have ID,Name,Category,Value, etc.

Comment: How do you get you results from these tables? If you are using an ORM you should be able to get good normalized object trees.

Comment: Yes I use EF, and most of the fields I need are navigation properties.

Answer (score 3):

If your class is really long and you don't want to copy all the stuff, you can try something like this:

```
l.GroupBy(x => x.id).
  Select(x => {
    var ret = x.First();
    ret.value = x.Sum(xt => xt.value);
    return ret;
  }).ToList();
```

With great power great responsibility comes. You need to be careful. Line `ret.value = x.Sum(xt => xt.value)` **will change** your original collection, as you are passing reference, not new object. If you want to avoid it, you need to add some `Clone` method into your class like `MemberwiseClone` (but again, this will create shallow copy, so be careful). Afer that just replace the line with: `var ret = x.First().Clone();`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var objList = new List<SampleObject>();

objList.Add(new SampleObject() { ID = 1, Value = 5, Name = "Name1", Category = "Catergory1"});
objList.Add(new SampleObject() { ID = 1, Value = 7, Name = "Name1", Category = "Catergory1"});
objList.Add(new SampleObject() { ID = 2, Value = 1, Name = "Name2", Category = "Catergory2"});
objList.Add(new SampleObject() { ID = 3, Value = 6, Name = "Name3", Category = "Catergory3"});
objList.Add(new SampleObject() { ID = 3, Value = 2, Name = "Name3", Category = "Catergory3"});

var newList = from val in objList
              group val by new { val.ID, val.Name, val.Category } into grouped
              select new SampleObject() { ID = grouped.ID, Value = grouped.Sum(), Name = grouped.Name, Category = grouped.Category };
```

to check with LINQPad:

```
newList.Dump();
```