# Sum of marks based on ID of a generic in List in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics

I am trying to do aggregate functions in a list of generics in C# based on an id

```
class Student{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public int marks { get; set; }
}

class Main {
  List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
  List.Add(new Student(1,55);
  List.Add(new student(2,65);
  List.Add(new student(4,75);
  List.Add(new student(1,65);
  List.Add(new student(2,45);

  foreach(var st in StudentList) {
    Console.WriteLine(st.id + " " + st.marks);
  }
}
```

But this returns

```
1 55
2 65
4 75
1 65
2 45
```

I want to return the following result:

```
1 120
2 110
4 75
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100900/select-multiple-fields-group-by-and-sum

Comment: Please take more care when posting code, this one is littered with errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select multiple fields group by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100900/select-multiple-fields-group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the Linq `GroupBy` function:

```
var totals = StudentList
    .GroupBy(sl => sl.id) //Group by ID
    .Select(g => new Student(g.Key, g.Sum(s => s.marks)));

foreach (var st in totals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(st.id + " " + st.marks);
}
```

Comment: Can you also add a solution without using Linq?

Comment: No, you should be able to do that yourself.

Comment: I cannot. I am trying. Can you please help. I will really appreciate it

Comment: I've already answered your question, you can't keep asking for more.

Comment: Can we convert var totals to List so I can perform further operations on it?

Comment: Yes, add `.ToList()` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can also group with a `Dictionary<int, int>`.

**With LINQ:**

```
var Totals = StudentList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(i => i.Mark).Sum());
```

**Without LINQ:**

```
var Totals = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (var student in StudentList)
{
    var id = student.Id;
    if (!Totals.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        Totals[id] = 0;
    }

    Totals[id] += student.Mark;
}
```

Then you can simply print out the results like this:

```
foreach (var result in Totals)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Key} {result.Value}");
}
```

Which Outputs:

```
1 120
2 110
4 75
```