# Merge the rows of a list into a single row

Tags: c#

I have a payment class similar to the following

```
class Payment
{
    public int ContactId {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
}
```

In a payment list, I would like to sum the **Amount** field for the rows that have the same value in the **ContactId** field and then in the **Data** field.

Here is an example:

```
List<Payment> payments;
Payment payment;
payment = new Payment
{
    ContactId = 1,
    Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2018"),
    Amount = 1m
}
payments.Add(payment);

payment = new Payment
{
    ContactId = 1,
    Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2018"),
    Amount = 1m
}
payments.Add(payment);

payment = new Payment
{
    ContactId = 2,
    Date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2018"),
    Amount = 1m
}
payments.Add(payment);
```

So I have a list of three elements.

I look for a solution that in this case gives me back a list consisting of two rows.

Row 1: ContactId=1; Date="01/01/2018"; Amount=2;

Row 2: ContactId=2; Date="01/01/2018"; Amount=1;

Comment: What have you tried? Have you met `linq`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - group/sum multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955475/linq-group-sum-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to group by `ContactId` and the `Date` and get the sum of `Amount`?

Easiest approach is using LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Payment> contactDateGroups = payments
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.ContactId, x.Date.Date })
   .Select(g => new Payment{ 
        ContactId = g.Key.ContactId,
        Date = g.Key.Date,
        Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. It is the solution I was looking for.