# Is it possible to group data for 2 columns using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following code which fetches data from an Entify Framework DB.

```
return r.Find()
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
        .Select(x => new ProductCount
                     {
                         ProductID = x.Key,
                         Quantity = x.Count()
                     })
        .ToList();
```

As you can see the data is grouped on ProductID and a count is returned. Product is a child of Buyer which is also in the same entity, so I wondered if it would be possible to return a count at both Product level and Buyer level in one transaction.

Into a class such as:

```
public class BuyerAndProductCount
{
    public int BuyerID { get; set; }
    public int BuyerCount { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE

Here is the entity that is being queried.

```
public partial class ApplicationHistory
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public decimal Commission { get; set; }
    public long ResponseTimeMS { get; set; }
    public string ResponseInfo { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ApplicantID { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationResultID { get; set; }
    public int BuyerID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How exactly would `BuyerCount` be calculated? Please show an example input set and the resulting output.

Comment: Please provide a definition of your entity, a.k.a. a complete code sample, so that answers can be correct.

Comment: The entity consists of a number of ID's, including BuyerID and ProductID - its simply a case of counting the number of Buyer transactions, just like the product transactions are counted.

Comment: Where is your BuyerID coming from? It is not in your `ApplicationHistory` class? This is not answerable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group By Multiple Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using an anonymous type in the `GroupBy` method, for sample:

```
return r.Find()
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductID, x.BuyerID })
        .Select(x => new ProductCount
                     {
                         ProductID = x.Key.ProductID,
                         Quantity = x.Count()
                     })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - as you can see from the output class, I'm looking to return 2 counts - 1 for the Buyer and 1 for the Product

Comment: from his code you should be able to extract a working solution for 2 counts... create 1st groupby into var, create 2nd groupby into other var, combine 2 vars into return value..