# Select more than one columns when using Group By

Tags: sql, entity-framework, group-by

Is it possible to select more than one columns in entity framework than just key & value when doing Group By.

Comment: I think this is duplicate to the following question 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns>

Comment: @HossamEl-Deen, It is not. In the link OPD wants to group by multiple columns.

Comment: Here I want to group by only one column but select multiple columns, not just the key & value.