# C# List<t> Combining items with a matching "code" on the same date

Tags: c#, list

I have a list comprised of (at a basic level) a date, code and value. I need to combine any items with the same code from the same date. I would appreciate any help in this.

```
ex.
Code       Date    Value
A1000   06-29-2015   5
A1000   06-29-2015   3
A1000   06-29-2015   1
A2000   06-29-2015   5
A2000   06-29-2015   5
A1000   06-28-2015   9
A1000   06-28-2015   5

I need the resulting list to look as follows
A1000   06-29-2015   9
A2000   06-29-2015   10
A1000   06-28-2015   14
```

Comment: Specifically see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/847426/961113

Comment: Sorry, that link did help. Thank you.