# Group By with multiple column

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have data in a table as below

> ```
> RowId | User | Date 
> --------------------------
>   1     A     2015-11-11 08:50:48.243
>   2     A     2015-11-11 08:51:01.433
>   3     B     2015-11-11 08:51:05.210
> ```

Trying to get the data as below:

> ```
> User, Date,        Count
>   A   2015-11-11     2
>   B   2015-11-11     1
>
>  Select User,Date,Count(User) from Table1 
>  Group By User,Date
> ```

It is returning me 3 rows because of time involved in Date field. 
How to get this in SQL and Linq.
Please suggest me.

EDITING:

I am able to get it in SQL

> ```
>  Select User,Cast(Date as Date),Count(User) from Table1 
>  Group By User,Cast(Date as Date)
> ```

EDITING:

adding linq query

> ```
> var details = db.table1.GroupBy( r => new { r.RowId,r.User,r.Date})
> .Select(g => new {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}).ToList();
> ```

Comment: Edited the question. Need help in linq

Comment: Where is your linq query? i.e. show what you have tried.

Comment: please add the LInQ code you currently have so we can modify it

Comment: @user1893874 I added the correct Linq query that will not need to calcul in memory. All are done on the server database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group By Multiple Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: @CraigW. Indeed it seems to be the same question but here you need to group by keys which contains DateTime. The group by must be about the date without the time part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linq Query just do the following: (you need to import using `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer` namespace.

Execute this linq query all calculations are done on the server database. Notice that `Table1s` represents the `DbSet` for `Table1` and `context` is your `DbContext` instance.

```
var query = from item in context.Table1s
    group item by new
    {
       item.User, 
       Year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", item.Date), 
       Month = SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", item.Date), 
       Day = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd", item.Date)
    } into g
    select new { g.Key.User, g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day, Count = g.Count() };
```

Then create the final result like this:

```
var result = query.ToList().Select(p =>
    new
    {
        p.User,
        Date = new DateTime(p.Year.Value, p.Month.Value, p.Day.Value),
        p.Count
    }).ToList();
```

Other solution is to create a SQL View that will be used by DbContext to retrive the data you want. The SQL View body must be the SQL your wrote in your question.

**EDIT 2 : DbFunctions**

Like Cetin Basoz pointed in comments we can use **System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions** as well. And the code is more cleaner than using **SqlFunctions**. This will work only with EF 6 and greater. The version using SqlFunctions work with EF 4 and greater.

```
var query = from item in context.Table1s
    group item by new
    {
        item.User, 
        Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(item.Date)
    } into g
    select new { g.Key.User, g.Key.Date, Count = g.Count() };
```

**EDIT 1 : this is specific for Cetin Basoz's answer :**

As we all know using AsEnumerable is not efficient for doing what is needed. 
The second solution he gives us which is :

```
var grouped = from d in db.MyTable
          group d by new {
  User = d.User, 
  Date=d.Date.HasValue ? d.Date.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null} into g
  select new {User=g.Key.User, Date=g.Key.Date, Count=g.Count()};
```

This solution just not work because of this :

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Although this is marked as an answer, did you try this one at all? How would this work with a nullable date column (which is common for a date/Datetime column). Otherwise I could do the original one simply with d,Date.Date and remove the AsEnumerable.

Comment: Thinking about it again, and retesting, I didn't need the AsEnumerable at all and it worked right server side. I don't know why I saw multiple queries sent to server in first test (must be some left over code).

Comment: Just edit your answer then. Stop flooding others posts. This Is not a compétition and explain why you don't need AsEnumerable. Thanks

Comment: @CetinBasoz just check my edited answer and we know why your code not work.

Comment: That is not a correct explanation. Date is supported by Linq To SQL. If it is not Linq To SQL then why would you use SqlFunctions? Are they suppported by Linq To EF?

Comment: `System.Data.Entity` is all about Linq To Entities. `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`is all about Linq to Entites specfic for SQL Server. Nothing doing here with Linq TO SQL. SqlFunctions contains methods that can be translated to SQL Server specific functions for EF.

Comment: I mean if you are using SqlFunctions then you are implying that you are using Linq To SQL, no? I didn't know I could use SqlFunctions in EF and against any database. Maybe then you should instead use DbFunctions.TruncateTime().

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about DbFunctions which work with EF6 and greater. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm if EF4 is a concern, then you could use EntityFunctions which later replaced with DbFunctions.

Comment: We can still use SqlFunctions which is SQL Server Specific. Rather EntityFunctions is not. SQlFunctions, EntityFunctions and DbFunctions all work well.DbFunctions will remain but EntityFunctions and SqlFunctions will maybe in the future removed. They are just a wrapper and perform sometimes same things.

Answer (score 0):

If the time is the problem, you can first convert it:

```
select User, CAST(dateColumn AS DATE) as dateConverted
into #tempTable
from myTable
```

then using a window function or a group by:

```
select *,
    count(user) over (partition by date) as userCount
    from #tempTable
```

This should work in SQL server, don't know about Linq

edit: If the date part is the problem, just `select into` from your table to a table with the casted date. Then you won't have this problem in Linq.

Comment: There i no need to create a temporary table for that. Check the question. The User already have a solution for TSQL

Comment: he added the solution after i wrote my response.

Comment: Yes, I need help in Linq.

Comment: Why don't you try as I suggested? just take your table and select into another with the date casted. Then use that one in Linq? Will this work? Worth a shot

Comment: @CM2K your solution waste a ressource because you create a temporary table which is not the best solution

Comment: @CodeNotFound True, but since I don't have any experience with Linq i simply suggested something which may work and solve the problem. Maybe the OP didn't think of this, happens

Answer (score 0):

```
var grouped = from d in db.MyTable.AsEnumerable()
              group d by new {
      User = d.User, 
      Date=d.Date.HasValue ? d.Date.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null} into g
              select new {User=g.Key.User, Date=g.Key.Date, Count=g.Count()};
```

Sooner or later, someone would say that this is not server side grouping and would suffer from performance and they would be right. Without Enumerable it is serverside but at the cost of another call per group, so here is another way:

```
public class MyResult
{
  public string User {get;set;}
  public DateTime? Date {get;set;}
  public int Count {get;set;}
}

var grouped = db.ExecuteQuery<MyResult>(@"select [User], 
  Cast([Date] as Date) as [Date],
  Count(*) as [Count]
from myTable
group by [user], Cast([Date] as Date)");
```

EDIT: I don't know why I thought the other way before, this would just work serverside and do it, AsEnumerable() was not needed:

```
var grouped = from d in db.MyTable
              group d by new {
      User = d.User, 
      Date=d.Date.HasValue ? d.Date.Value.Date : (DateTime?)null} into g
  select new {User=g.Key.User, Date=g.Key.Date, Count=g.Count()};
```

Comment: You can do will just one call to the server side lik I did in my answer and Without Enumerable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and answer.

Comment: If you think that a datetime column is likely accepts NULL values, then using SqlFunctions would not work.

Comment: Anyway just deal with my new edited answer. Your code throwz an exception at runtime. I will not downvote your post because we are not here for getting award or in competition.