# C#.NET LinQ remove Dupes from list with a twist

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Company objects with name, address, email, etc. I need a way to sort the list by company name (which I can easily do). But then I need to compare the email and city. If one of those matches a company with the same name, I need to remove BOTH of them.

I can easily do the .First to get one and remove the matching one but I need the original to be removed from the list as well. Make sense?
The bottom 2 LINQ statements remove the duplicate but not the original

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 10749; i++) //Range.UsedRange isnt working for some reason so I hard coded the row numbers
{
    firm = new Firm();
    string begCell;
    begCell = "B" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.acctNo = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "C" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.name = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "D" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.addy1 = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "E" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.city = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "F" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.state = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "G" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.zip = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "H" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.phone = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "I" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    firm.email = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

    begCell = "AB" + i;
    excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
    if (Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2).Equals("Active", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        firm.active = true;

    if (firm.active)
        firmList.Add(firm);

}

var sortedList = firmList.OrderBy(o => o.name).ToList();
var removeDupEmails = firmList.GroupBy(x => x.name).SelectMany(x =>
                             x.OrderByDescending(y => y.email)
                             .Take(1)
                         );
var removeDupZips = firmList.GroupBy(x => x.name).SelectMany(x =>
                             x.OrderByDescending(y => y.addy)
                             .Take(1)
                         );
```

Comment: You can `GroupBy` on multiple columns using anonymous objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Comment: Note that there's ambiguity in this comparison. Suppose two companies have the same name, but different Email and City. So they're not duplicates. Now there is a third company having the same name, and Email of company1 and City of company2. Does that make three duplicates, even though company1 and company2 aren't duplicates?

Comment: if they have the (same name and addy) OR (same name and email) OR (same addy and email) then they are considered duplicates. I was unclear on that so it is my fault. I apoligize

Comment: OK, let's have company c1: A,B,C (name, email,city), c2: A,D,E. Not equal right? Add c3: A,B,E. Now we have c1 = c3 and c2 = c3, but c1 != c2. It doesn't compute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.  Instead of removing only add the ones that meet the criteria.  I updated the code.  Found some errors.

```
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
            var groups = companies.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.name)
                .Select(x => x.Where(y => (x.Select(z => z.email).ToList().Where(s => s == y.email).Count() == 1) && (x.Select(z => z.addy).ToList().Where(s => s == y.addy).Count() == 1)).Select(a => a)).SelectMany(b => b).ToList();


        }

    }
    public class Company
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string email {get;set;}
        public string addy {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks and forgive my ignorance but the code isnt able to run. the part that is giving me issues is: y => x.SelectMany(z => !z.email.Contains(y.email)). The error is Error 5 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate duplicates, you can use the following pattern:

```
source.GroupBy(element => element.Property) // Split the list in groups by the property you want to check
.Where(propertyGroup => propertyGroup.Count() > 1) // Filter the duplicates
.SelectMany(propertyGroup => propertyGroup) // Flatten back the result set
```

If I understand correctly the concrete question, you can achieve the desired result with a single query like this:

```
var resultList = firmList
    .GroupBy(firm => firm.name)
    .OrderBy(nameGroup => nameGroup.Key)
    .SelectMany(nameGroup => nameGroup
        .GroupBy(firm => firm.email)
        .Where(emailGroup => emailGroup.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(emailGroup => emailGroup)
        .GroupBy(firm => firm.addy)
        .Where(addyGroup => addyGroup.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(addyGroup => addyGroup)
    )
    .ToList();
```