# LINQ (method) returning multiple records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Have two models, `Case` and `Client`:

```
public class Case
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently using the following LINQ method call to query these structures so that I can retrieve a list of Client Id's and Name's based on the status of any Case that is associated with them

```
    public ActionResult Index(string status)
    {
        var query = _context.Cases
            .Include(c => c.Client);
        if (status != "all")
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.Status == status);
        }

        var cases = query.ToList();

        return View(cases);
    }
```

My problem is that if I have multiple cases for the same client, it retrieves that Id and Name multiple times.

Am I approaching this from the wrong angle, or what is suggested to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `Distinct()` like

```
    if (status != "all")
    {
        query = query.Where(c => c.Status == status).Distinct();
    }
```

Comment: That will only pull the first Client that has a Case of the status.  Its the Case.Client.Id that needs to be distinct

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy multiple properties using an anonymus type as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns) where you can use `Id` and `Name` in the anonymus type. At the end of the query you can add: `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name })`

```
var cases = query.ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to work for me.  I can view the `cases` object in debug mode and the data seems correct.  If I am correct, the @model statement in my View should be `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<new { int Id, string Name },LegalMinder.Models.Case >>` but I get the following two errors:  `Using the generic List<T> requires 1 type arguments` and `Using the generic type IGrouping<TKey, TElement> requires 2 type arguments`. Is that not what I have in my statement?

Comment: Hi @KeithClark I forgot the last select clause, you can try now

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a Select to the `var cases = query.ToList();` and then calling the Distinct() method.

So my final code looks like:

```
var cases = query.Select(c => c.Client).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
```

@Rahul - Had the right concept, just in the wrong place, but it pointed me down the right path. Thanks!

@meJustAndrew - I liked the approach, but still got hung up on the @model statement.  If you can add any comments on where I went wrong, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a property `Cases` to `Client` you can make the query more economical:

```
public ActionResult Index(string status)
{
    IQueryable<Client> query = _context.Clients;
    if (status != "all")
    {
        query = query.Where(c => c.Cases.Any(cs => cs.Status == status));
    }

    var clients = query.ToList();
    // or query.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name }) ?

    return View(clients);
}
```

This avoids a relatively expensive `Include` and processing to get unique client.

In general, it's usually better to start a query by the data you want to return in the end and build the predicates off of that entity.