# Group By struct list on multiple columns in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a struct as

```
public struct structMailJob
{
 public string ID;
 public string MailID;
 public int ResendCount;
 public int PageCount;
}
```

and a list as

```
List<structMailJob> myStructList = new List<structMailJob>();
```

I have loaded data in *myStructList* from database and want myStructList data in a new list after grouping by  MailID and ResendCount.

I am trying as:

```
List<structMailJob> newStructList = new List<structMailJob>();

newStructList = myStructList.GroupBy(u => u.MailID, u=>u.ResendCount)
                                  .Select(grp => new { myStructList = grp.ToList() })
                                  .ToList();
```

but unable to do that as getting error message - *cant implicitly convert generic list to structMailJob.*

Comment: Please go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: use var variable and check the query.check weather it is a type error@gaurav

Comment: The 'grp => new { myStructList = grp.ToList() }' statement creates an anonymous object whose sole property is a list named myStructList. This type will be the resulting collection's item,
Whereas you expect a collection of your specific type.
The collection types do not match, hence the exception.
<br>
I would gladly help you achieve your cause if you tell me what it is you want to do with the data.. there are a couple of ways to go about this which depend on the use case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq Query is completely incorrect, following are the important points:

`myStructList.GroupBy(u => u.MailID, u=>u.ResendCount)` // Incorrect grouping

`myStructList.GroupBy(u => new {u.MailID, u.ResendCount })` // Correct grouping, which will do by two columns `MailID` and `ResendCount`, last one was only doing by `MailID` and was using `ResendCount` for result projection

Now the result is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<AnonymousType,structMailJob>>`, so when you do something like `Select`, it will end up creating Concatenated List of type `IEnumerable<List<structMailJob>>` (Removed the assignment to `myStructList` inside the Select, as that was not correct):

```
.Select(grp => grp.ToList())
```

Correct code would require you to flatten using `SelectMany` as follows:

```
newStructList = myStructList.GroupBy(u => new {u.MailID, u.ResendCount})
                                      .SelectMany(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

Assign it to `newStructList`, but this code has little use, since literally `newStructList` is exactly same as `myStructList` post flattening, ideally you shall be able to use the grouping, so that you can get a subset and thus the correct result, however that depends on your business logic

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for is the following:

```
var newStructList = myStructList.GroupBy(smj => new { smj.MailID, smj.ResendCount })
                                .Select(grp => new 
                                { 
                                    MailID = grp.Key.MailID,
                                    ResendCount = grp.Key.ResendCount
                                    MailJobs = grp.Select(x=>new 
                                               {
                                                   x.ID,
                                                   x.PageCount
                                               }).ToList() 
                                })
                                .ToList();
```

Note that we changed the `GroupBy` clause to the following one:

```
GroupBy(smj => new { smj.MailID, smj.ResendCount })
```

Doing so, the key on which the groups would be created would be consisted of both  `MailID` and `ResendCount`. By the way the former `GroupBy` clause isn't correct.

Then having done the grouping, we project each group to an object with three properties, `MailID` and `ResendCout`, which are the components of the key and list of anonymous type object with two properties, `ID` and `PageCount`, which we gave it the name MailJobs.

Last but not least you will notice that I didn't mention the following

```
List<structMailJob> newStructList = new List<structMailJob>();
```

I just used the `var` and declared the `newStructList`. I *don't think that you stated in your post makes sense*. How do we expect to get a list of the same objects after grouping them? So I *assumed* that you might want is the above.

However, I thought you might want also something like this and you didn't want to refer to *Grouping*.

```
myStructList = myStructList.OrderBy(smj => smj.MailID)
                           .ThenBy(smj => smj.ResendCount)
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, in your first solution there is small typo i guess, have added smj. as new { smj.MailID, smj.ResendCount } and comma after ResendCount = grp.Key.ResendCount,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right but it seems to me you missed the 'Group by' signature.

```
List<structMailJob> myStructList = new List<structMailJob>();

List<structMailJob> newStructList = new List<structMailJob>();

newStructList = myStructList
    // .GroupBy(/*Key Selector */u => u.MailID, /*Element Selector*/u=>u.ResendCount)           
    .GroupBy(u => new { u.MailID, u.ResendCount }) // broup by MailID, ResendCount
    // Note no Element Selector , the 'STRUCT' is 'SELECTED'
    .Select(grp => {
        // NOte: Key ==  Anonymous {MailID, ResendCount } 
        return grp;
    })
    // otherwise you get a IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> instead of IEnumerable<T> because you grouped it
    .SelectMany(x=>x)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If Mrinal Kamboj's answer is what you are looking for, then you could use the following as an alternative:

```
  var orderedList = myStructList.OrderBy(x => x.MailID).ThenBy(x => x.ResendCount);
```