# Group By + Select into New Nested Class Structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | animal  | type   |
+----+---------+--------+
|  0 | dog     | TypeA  |
|  1 | cat     | TypeA  |
|  2 | dog     | TypeB  |
|  3 | cat     | TypeB  |
+----+---------+--------+
```

**Obviously what I want to do is using GroupBy in EF which somehow like this:**

- *dbAnimal.GroupBy(x => x.animal);*

But what if I want to furtherly map the data into the below class structure?

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        this.animalType = new List<Type>();
    }

    public string animalDesc { get; set; }
    public List<Type> animalType { get; set; }

    public class Type
    {
        public string typeDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example in JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "animalDesc": "dog",
        "animalType": 
        [
            {
                "typeDesc": "TypeA",
            },
            {
                "typeDesc": "TypeB",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "animalDesc": "cat",
        "animalType": 
        [
            {
                "typeDesc": "TypeA",
            },
            {
                "typeDesc": "TypeB",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My question is how to achieve the mapping to class model after using GroupBy in EF.

Other workaround are also welcome too. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this class that represent your database table mapping

```
public class DatabaseAnimal {
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string animal { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

And these classes to represent the projection you want to do

```
public class Animal {
    public Animal() {
        animalType = new List<AnimalType>();
    }

    public string animalDesc { get; set; }
    public List<AnimalType> animalType { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalType {
    public string typeDesc { get; set; }    
}
```

You can project (using `Select`) your group into your model

```
var result = dbAnimal.GroupBy(a => a.animal)
                     .Select(grp => new Animal {
                         animalDesc = grp.Key,
                         animalType = grp.Select(e => new AnimalType {
                             typeDesc = e.type 
                         }).ToList()
                      });
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HEZq8H)

Also, I highly suggest you adopt [C# Capitalization Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) as a naming convention in your classes.