# Groupby multiple date properties by month and year in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, grouping

I need to group by multiple properties by month and year in `C#` `LINQ`

This is my code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> dt1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> dt2 { get; set; }
}

Class1 obj1 = new Class1 { dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 11, 12),
                           dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12) };
Class1 obj2 = new Class1 { dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 11, 12),
                           dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12) };
Class1 obj3 = new Class1 { dt1 = null, dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 12) };
Class1 obj4 = new Class1 { dt1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 12), dt2 = null };
Class1 obj5 = new Class1 { dt1 = null, dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 11, 12) };
Class1 obj6 = new Class1 { dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 10, 12), dt2 = null };

List<Class1> listGoogleTimezone = new List<Class1>
{
    obj1,
    obj2,
    obj3,
    obj4,
    obj5,
    obj6
};
```

My required result to be like this

```
MONTH YEAR   COUNT
```

```
OCT   2012   2
NOV   2012   3
DEC   2012   2
```

Help me out

Comment: Which of the two dates do you want to group by? You have only one date in the output, but two in the input.

Comment: I need both the date properties to groupby

Comment: And where is your problem? `result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.dt1, x.dt2 })`.

Comment: I am new to LINQ and I do not know how to group by two date fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group By Multiple Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to collect all the dates using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) (in this particular case filter out the `null` values) and then do the typical `GroupBy` / `Count` projection:

```
var result = listGoogleTimezone
    .SelectMany(x => new[] { x.dt1, x.dt2 }.Where(dt => dt != null).Select(dt => dt.Value))
    .GroupBy(dt => new { dt.Month, dt.Year })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Year).ThenBy(g => g.Key.Month) // optional
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Month,
        g.Key.Year,
        Count = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have [`MoreLinq`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) referenced you can use make *Ivan*'s answer cleaner by using [`CountBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_CountBy__2.htm):

```
var result = listGoogleTimezone
    .SelectMany(x => new[] { x.dt1, x.dt2 }
        .Where(dt => dt != null)
        .Select(dt => dt.Value))
    .CountBy(x => new { Year = x.Year, Month = x.Month });
```

This will can you an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, int>>` where the `TKey` is an anonymous type with `Year` and `Month` and the `int` is the count.