# SelectMany c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry to open another post.

[.SelectMany with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112943/selectmany-with-c-sharp/43113135?noredirect=1#comment75875786_43113135)

I asked in the previous post but I can't get the solution for my problem.

`

```
var departments = stops 
    .Where(stop => stop.InitDate != null)
    .SelectMany(stop => new[] { Month = stop.InitDate.Month, Year = stop.InitDate.Year, Duration = stop.Duration })
    .GroupBy(dt => new { dt.Month, dt.Year }) 
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Month)
    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.Year) 
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        Key = g.Key.Month, 
        Año = g.Key.Year, 
        Duration = g.Sum(v => v.Duration), 
        Count = g.Count() 
    });
```

`

This is de final solution to my problem, but, when I use this in my code, I have some problems.

If I don't declare the variables "Month, Year, Duration", I get an error in:
`.SelectMany(stop => new[] { Month = stop.InitDate.Month, Year = stop.InitDate.Year, Duration = stop.Duration })`

But I do not know what kind of data they are month and year because if I declare it how integer, I get an error in `.GroupBy(dt => new { dt.Month, dt.Year })`, because the compiler recognizes dt as integer.

I tried to declare Month and Year as integer and put in the .GroupBy this:
`.GroupBy(dt => new { Month, Year })` but it is not correct...

Thank you in advance

Raúl

Comment: use `new` instead of `new[]`

Comment: You don't need `SelectMany` here. It is used to flatten sequences into one sequence. You don't have any sequences in your stop object. Also sorting by month on first place looks strange

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.SelectMany with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112943/selectmany-with-c-sharp)....Dont ask duplicate questions especially when the first one already has answers

Comment: I think that I need SelectMany because I want order by year and after by month... I need to group all durations for each month-year couple

Comment: @RaúlBerros, as EpicKip said, don't post the same question more times, it's not how SO is supposed to work. If you don't receive satisfying answers, post a bounty on your question to attract more users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have a sequence named `Stops` which is a sequence of `stop` objects. Each `stop` object may or may have not an `InitDate`. If it has an `InitDate`, this `InitDate` has at least properties `Month`, `Year` and `Duration`, which are all `int`.

What you want is from your original `Stops`, only those `stop` objects that have an `InitDate`. From every `stop` object you select, you want to create a new object, with a `Key` property which contains the Month and the Year and a `Duration` property which contains the Duration.

> You were almost there. Your problem was that you used `SelectMany` instead of a simple `Select`.

Normally you use `SelectMany` if you have a sequence of sequences that you want to concatenate into one sequence. However your `Stops` does not have a sequence of sequences. Every `stop` object should produce one "new object with Year, Month and Duration".

Or in simple words: whenever you have a collection of "thingies" and you want to convert every "thingy" into exactly one "other thingy", you should use `Select`, not `SelectMany`:

In your case the Select will be:

```
var stopData = stops 
   .Where(stop => stop.InitDate != null)
   .Select(stop => new
   { 
       GroupKey = new 
       {
           Month = stop.InitDate.Month,
           Year = stop.InitDate.Year,
       },
       Duration = stop.Duration
   });
```

I put the Year and the Month alreay in a property GroupKey, because that makes the grouping easier:

```
var groupsOfSameMonth = stopData
    .GroupBy( item => item.Key, item => item.Duration);
```

Now every group, contains a key, which is the {Month, Year}. The elements of the group are all Durations with this {month, year}. So now all you have to do is from every group, take all elements from the group and Sum() and Count() them:

```
var durationsOfSameMonth = groupsOfSameMonth
    .Select(group => new 
    { 
       Month = group.Key.Month, // I assumed your Key was an error
       Año = group.Key.Year, 
       Duration = group.Sum(), 
       Count = group.Count() 
    });
```

All you have to do is some ordering and you are finished.

Comment: Did you mean to use `SelectMany` in your first snippet?

Comment: oops, my fault. Corrected