# C# grouping loses row

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have got the following SQL-Table:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ID | Line1    | Line2  | Line3  | Line4 | Line5 |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Software | Citrix | XenApp | Null  | Null  |
---------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Software | Citrix | XenApp | Null  | Null  |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I used this code in order to group it by Line3:

```
var KategorienLine3 = result.GroupBy(x => x.Line3).ToList();
```

In which result represents the list including the 2 entries.
Now this grouping results in this output:

```
[0] -> Key = XenApp
[1] -> Key = XenApp
```

But I don't have access to Line2. I would like to include it in the result. How can I do that, so that I have access to that as well?
It don't want to group by it!! I just want to have it in the result.

Thats what it gives me after the grouping. I want to include Line2 as well.
[image]

Comment: I do not see sql code ..

Comment: You will have to group by Line2 as well (in addition to Line3).

Comment: result.GroupBy(x => x.Line3, x => x.Line2).ToList();
I tried this, but it still shows nonly the key... @hatchet

Comment: What is the way you want to see that data after the grouping

Comment: Let me append a screenshot, I want to see the "Citrix" as well.

Comment: Also - all data besides id is identical - is it really like that, duplicated data, or just in the given example

Comment: It is just an example to make it easier

Comment: @Anokrize - it will make it easier if you show a better example of the data and then also what is the expected output (and remember that when grouping then each key has several items for it)

Comment: See the screenshot @GiladGreen

Comment: The expected output should be: Line2 -> Citrix, Line3 -> XenApp

Comment: @Anokrize see the answer to this question regarding grouping on multiple columns. Note the use of anonymous type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Comment: The result of `GroupBy` is a `IGrouping<TKey, TResult>` which it's itself an `IEnumerable<TResult>`.  So the `Key` will be `Line3` and you would iterate over the rows in the group to get the other columns like `KategorienLine3[0].Select(r => r.Line2).ToList()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is there. It is just in the `IGrouping<TKey, TResult>` object returned by the `GroupBy`. The reason you *don't have access* to `Line2` is that each grouping contains a collection of records that are of that group - and each record there is of your object's type, and has the `Line2` property.

To retrieve it project the data as you want it to show:

```
// method syntax
var result  = data.GroupBy(key => key.Line3, item => item.Line2)
                  .Select(g => new
                  {
                      g.Key,
                      Line2 = g.ToList()
                  }).ToList();

// query syntax
var result = from item in data
             group item.Line2 by item.Line3 into g
             select new
             {
                 g.Key,
                 Line2 = g.ToList()
             };
```