# C# change from groupby

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Suppose there are two properties in `Myclass`: `Date`, `Symbol`
I want to frequently convert between those two properties, but I find that
for `List <Myclass> vector`
if I use

```
vector.groupby(o => o.Date).Select(o => o)
```

the `vector` is  no longer the type of `List<IGrouping<string, Myclass>>`

And if I want to convert `groupby(o => o.Date)` to `groupby(o => o.Symbol)`
I have to use

```
vector.groupby(o => o.Date).Selectmany(o => o).groupby(o => o.Symbol)
```

I try to use `SortedList<Date, Myclass>`, but I am not familiar with `SortedList`(actually, I don't know what's the difference between `SortedList` and `Groupby`). 
Is there any effective way to achieve such effect, as I highly depend on the speed of running?

```
int volDay = 100;
Datetime today = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);

//choose the effective database used today, that is the symbol with data more than volDay
var todayData = dataBase.Where(o => o.Date <= today).OrderByDescending(o => o.Date)
                .GroupBy(o => o.Symbol).Select(o => o.Take(volDay))
                .Where(o => o.Count() == volDay).SelectMany(o => o);

//Select symbols we want today
var symbolList = todayData
                .Where(o => o.Date == today && o.Eqy_Dvd_Yld_12M > 0))
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.CUR_MKT_CAP)
                .Take((int)(1.5 * volDay)).Where(o => o.Close > o.DMA10)
                .OrderBy(o => o.AnnualizedVolatility10)
                .Take(volDay).Select(o => o.Symbol).ToList();

//Select the database again only for the symbols in symbolList
var portfolios = todayData.GroupBy(o => o.Symbol)
               .Where(o=>symbolList.Contains(o.Key)).ToList();
```

This is my real code, `dataBase` is the total data, and I will run the cycle day by day(here just given a fixed day). The last List `portfolios` is the final goal I want obtain, you can ignore other properties, which are used for the selections under the collection of `Date` and `Symbol`

Comment: it looks pointless to first group by `Date` then by `Symbol`

Comment: why are you trying to group them?  what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ps2goat I want to do some operations for each `date` or `symbol`

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster, or at least easier to read, if you performed a `.Distinct()`.

To get distinct `Date`s:

`var distinctDates = vector.Select(o => o.Date).Distinct()`

To get distinct `Symbol`s:

`var distinctSymbols = vector.Select(o => o.Symbol).Distinct()`

I asked what you were trying to accomplish so that I can provide you with a useful answer.  Do you need both values together? E.g., the unique set of symbols and dates?  You should only need a single group by statement depending on what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

E.g., this question [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns) would be relevant if you want to group by multiple properties and track the two unique pieces of data.  a `.Distinct()` after the grouping should still work.

Comment: pls see the update, I just want to effectively obtain the list `portfolios`