# Group items based on a value in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have few records like below in a collection where two records have same item name and description(example: sample1 and item1) but some other fields are different,

```
1.sample1     item1   Rule2      Rule2msg        iteminfo2

2.sample1     item1   test1      testrule        iteminfo1
```

I need to group above records in linq in such a way that output is like below ,

```
Sample1,
item1,
{
    Rule2, 
    Rule2msg, 
    iteminfo2
},    
{
    testrule1 , 
    testrulemsg,
    iteminfo1
}
```

Basically what i am trying to achieve is since first two fields (itemName and Desc) is same , group them into single item and nest the remaining fields under the item so that item name is not duplicated and doesnt appear twice and appears as a single item. Any help is much appreciated

I have tried this

```
Itm.GroupBy(x => x.ITEM_NAME).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

it groups items , but as two records not as single item as what i expect.

Comment: Does the following link answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns?rq=1 check `.GroupBy(x => (x.Column1, x.Column2))`

Comment: @Rafalon this will still return two items under one item .but not as what i expect

Comment: So your question is about grouping them in a special structure ? How did you expect using `.Select(x => x.ToList())` to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should group the records on both the `itemName` and `Desc` columns.

```
Itm.GroupBy(x => new {x.ITEM_NAME, x.Desc}).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Well if this answers the question, then the question is a duplicate