# How to Group by and Sum for list data has been assigned List when using EntityFramwork and Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, arraylist

Table data is:

```
Info
----------------------------------------
num    name   age    expenseN    cost    group
1      a      20
2      b      21 

InfoDetail
----------------------------------------
num    expenseN    cost       group
1      001         10.00      x
2      001         20.00      x
3      002         20.00      x
4      003         30.00      y
```

This is code:

```
public class _infoRepository
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string expenseN { get; set; }
    public decimal cost { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
}
public class _infoDetailRepository
{
    public string expenseN { get; set; }
    public decimal cost { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
}


List<Info> result = new List<Info>();
var info = _infoRepository.Query(p => p.name = "a").FirstOrDefault();
var listInfoDetail = _infoDetailRepository.Query(p => p.group == "x").ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < listInfoDetail.Count; i++)
{
    result.Add(new Info()
    {
        name = info.name,
        age = info.age,
        expenseN = listInfoDetail[i].expenseN,
        cost = listInfoDetail[i].cost,
        group = listInfoDetail[i].group
    });
}
return result;
```

After running this code, the result of the `result` variable is as follows:

```
result
--------------------------------------------------
num    name   age    expenseN    cost      group
1      a      20     001         10.00     x
2      a      20     001         20.00     x
3      a      20     002         20.00     x
```

However, that was not the result I wanted, the result I expected was like this:

```
result
--------------------------------------------------
num    name   age    expenseN    cost      group
1      a      20     001         30.00     x
2      a      20     002         20.00     x
```

After all, i want to group by and sum the `result` variable to give me the desired result. Someone please help me in this situation, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: What is `_infoRepository.Query` etc. ?

Comment: aret the table's related?

Comment: hi Gert Arnold, `_infoRepository.Q` is all data taken from the `Info` table

Comment: If you ask a question you should show all code that's relevant to answering it. I.e. *show* the `.Query()` method, b/c I still don't know what it does *exactly* (f.e. whether it returns `IQueryable`).  Also show the `Info` and `InfoDetail` classes so we can see how they are related.

Comment: ok Gert Arnold, i understand

Comment: Because in my MVC system there are many files that are mapped together, so I'm afraid that will make my question too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `listInfoDetail` Must be grouped

Instead of

```
var listInfoDetail = _infoDetailRepository.Query(p => p.group == 
                     "x").ToList();
```

Use

```
 var listInfoDetail =_infoDetailRepository.Query(p => p.group =="x")
    .ToList().GroupBy(P=>new {P.expenseN, P.group})
    .Select(P=>new 
         {P.Key.expenseN, P.Key.group, cost=P.Sum(p=>p.cost)}
    );
```

Comment: hi Peter Isaac, i want to keep my code intact, is there a way to Group by and Sum for the last result variable?

Comment: what do you mean with last result variable? @TrietPham

Answer (score 0):

Update your for loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listInfoDetail.Count; i++)
        {
            if (result.Count(j => j.expenseN == listInfoDetail[i].expenseN) == 0)
            {
                result.Add(new Info
                {
                    name = info.name,
                    age = info.age,
                    expenseN = listInfoDetail[i].expenseN,
                    cost = listInfoDetail.Where(j => j.expenseN == listInfoDetail[i].expenseN).Sum(j => j.cost),
                    group = listInfoDetail[i].group
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: hi Praneet Nadkar, i want to keep my code intact, is there a way to Group by and Sum for the last result variable?

Comment: I am not sure what does last result variable mean. Do you mean the last item in the result list ?