# Convert T-sql to Linq or Entityframework and not to use SqlQuery() for raw queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a table which is called Signer :

```
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|     Name     |    User  |   Order | Signed | CompanyName  | Status  | InvoiceId |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|  Anders      |    aa    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26650 |
|  Peyman      |    pm    |       2 |      1 | OvnAnd2      |       1 |     26650 |
| Siw Ericsson |    se    |       3 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26650 |
|  test        |    test  |       4 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26650 |
|Siw Ericsson  |    se    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26652 |
|  test        |    test  |       2 |      1 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26652 |
|Siw Ericsson  |    se    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     25365 |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

Goal: 
As you can see I have 3 different InvoiceId's. For each InvoiceId, I would like to find a row with minimum order number that `Status` column's value is 0 and `User` column has to be `se`. 
( It means, Show the current users related invoices which are ready to be signed based on his/her username, order, signed columns)

I came up with this T-SQL which works fine :

```
select * from Signer s1
where s1.User = 'se' and Order = (select min(Order) from Signer s2 where s2.InvoiceId = s1.InvoiceId and Signed = 0)
```

And the result:

```
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|     Name     |    User  |   Order | Signed | CompanyName  | Status  | InvoiceId |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|Siw Ericsson  |    se    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26652 |
|Siw Ericsson  |    se    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     25365 |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

I would like to convert this query from `T-Sql` to `Linq` or `EntityFramework` :

This is my solution:

```
        var temp = from x in db.Signers
                    where x.User == Me.UserName &&
                          x.Signed == 0
                          group x by x.InvoiceId
                    into item
                    select new
                    {
                        item.Key,
                        item = item.Min(x => x.Order)
                    };
```

Which returns 3 rows which is wrong because Siw should see the related invoices that are ready to be signed by her. (It means the first row should not be in the list)

```
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|     Name     |    User  |   Order | Signed | CompanyName  | Status  | InvoiceId |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|  Anders      |    aa    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26650 |
|Siw Ericsson  |    se    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     26652 |
|Siw Ericsson  |    se    |       1 |      0 | OvnAnd2      |       0 |     25365 |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

More info:
- As you can see in the first table, we have a special logic that someone can sign invoices out of order and `Peyman` is one of them.
- I don't want to use `SqlQuery()` method in `Entityframework` in order to execute t-sql queries.

I appreciate any help to find a solution for my goal.
Best regards

Comment: I think you almost got it by yourself. if I goit it right, you only needed to do the grouping by two fields (InvoiceId and User) check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one of those situations where "let" come in handy:

```
var result = from s in Signers
    let minToSign = Signers.Where(si => 
        si.InvoiceId == s.InvoiceId && si.Signed == 0
    ).Min(si => si.Order)
    where s.User == "se" && s.Order == minToSign
    select s;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help