# Convert a flat list to a multi level hierarchy

Tags: c#

I have the following that needs to be converted to a multi level hierarchical tree.

```
public enum ERootType { NotUsed, RootType1, RootType2, }
public enum ESubType { NotUsed, SubTypeA, SubTypeB, SubTypeC, }

public class Payload { }

public class MyData
{
    public MyData(ERootType rootType, ESubType subType,
         string displayName, Payload payload)
    {
        RootType = rootType;
        SubType = subType;
        DisplayName = displayName;
        Payload = payload;
    }

    public ERootType RootType { get; }
    public ESubType SubType { get; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public object Payload { get; }

    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            Type myType = typeof(MyData);
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }
        set
        {
            Type myType = typeof(MyData);
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
}

// Create and initialize flat list of data
var Resources = new List<MyData>()
{
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType1, ESubType.SubTypeA, "Item1", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType1, ESubType.SubTypeA, "Item2", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType1, ESubType.SubTypeB, "Item3", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType1, ESubType.SubTypeB, "Item4", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType1, ESubType.SubTypeC, "Item5", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType2, ESubType.SubTypeA, "Item6", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType2, ESubType.SubTypeA, "Item7", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType2, ESubType.SubTypeB, "Item8", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType2, ESubType.SubTypeB, "Item9", new Payload()),
    new MyData(ERootType.RootType2, ESubType.SubTypeC, "Item10", new Payload()),
};
```

I need the above data converted to a hierarchical list that looks something like the following.

> - **RootType1** (ERootType = RootType1, ESubType = NotUsed, DiaplayName = "RootType1", Payload = null)
>
>   - **SubTypeA** (ERootType = NotUsed, ESubType = SubTypeA, DiaplayName = "SubTypeA", Payload = null)
>
>     - **Item1** (ERootType = RootType1, ESubType = SubTypeA, DiaplayName = "Item1", Payload = payload object instance)
>     - **Item2**
>   - **SubTypeB**
>
>     - **Item3**
>     - **Item4**
>   - **SubTypeC**
>
>     - **Item5**
> - **RootType2**
>
>   - **SubTypeA**
>
>     - **Item6**
>     - **Item7**
>   - **SubTypeB**
>
>     - **Item8**
>     - **Item9**
>   - **SubTypeC**
>
>     - **Item10**

I was trying to come up with a solution using Generics and Linq. I created the following class to support the hierarchical results.

```
public class TreeItem<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TreeItem<T>> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking that it would be good to have a generic method that could generate a tree with n levels by passing in an array of levels which are the names of the properties in the class being converted. I was thinking this method would use recursion. Here's a function declaration I was playing with.

```
public static IEnumerable<TreeItem<T>> GenerateNLevelTree<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
    string[] levelProps, int currentLevel = 0)
```

The class MyData contains a contains an indexer to support accessing the each property of MyData using a string.

Any help with a solution for generating the hierarchical data structure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please try to give your data prototype in json or xml format.

Comment: I haven't posted very many questions on this site and I haven't done much with json. Do you either have a quick explanation on how to do this or can you provide a link about how this is done. Thanks.

Comment: you can use group by cluase to build your hierarchy. but that wuod be complex for going level three or 4.

Comment: This looks like it might be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns.  Read all the answers, not just the accepted or high vote ones

Comment: I greatly updated my answer.  I believe it does what you want now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.  If you do something like this:

```
   var grouped1 = Resources.GroupBy(x => new {x.RootType, x.SubType, x.DisplayName});
   var grouped2 = grouped1.GroupBy(x => new {x.Key.RootType, x.Key.SubType});
   var grouped3 = grouped2.GroupBy(x => new {x.Key.RootType});
```

and they you traverse through the collections of collections in `grouped3`, you get a hierarchy similar to what you describe.  You'll probably want to translate that into something more semantically reasonable for your application.

BTW, Thanks for a great repro.  All the code needed to try this out was included.  That's pretty rare here.

### Update

What I did to navigate that `grouped3` thing was:

1. First create a bunch of classes to hold the bits of the hierarchy.

They all follow the same pattern:

```
 public class RootNode
 {
     private readonly List<SubNode> _subList = new List<SubNode>();
     public ERootType RootType { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<SubNode> Subs => _subList;

     public RootNode(ERootType rootType)
     {
         RootType = rootType;
     }

     public void AddSub(SubNode subNodeToAdd)
     {
         _subList.Add(subNodeToAdd);
     }
 }

public class SubNode
{
    private readonly List<ItemNode> _itemList = new List<ItemNode>();
    public ESubType SubType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemNode> Items => _itemList;

    public SubNode(ESubType subType)
    {
        SubType = subType;
    }

    public void AddItem(ItemNode itemToAdd)
    {
        _itemList.Add(itemToAdd);
    }
}

public class ItemNode
{
    private readonly List<Payload> _payloadList  = new List<Payload>();

    public string Item { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Payload> Payloads => _payloadList;
    public ItemNode(string item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public void AddPayload(Payload payloadToAdd)
    {
        _payloadList.Add(payloadToAdd);
    }
}
```

2. Then, right after the assignment of `grouped3` in the original code, I added this.

It just walks the `grouped3` mess and creates a bunch of nodes in a tree:

```
    var roots = new List<RootNode>();

    foreach (var root in grouped3)
    {
        var rootNode = new RootNode(root.Key.RootType);
        roots.Add(rootNode);
        foreach (var sub in root)
        {
            var subNode = new SubNode(sub.Key.SubType);
            rootNode.AddSub(subNode);
            foreach (var item in sub)
            {
                var itemNode = new ItemNode(item.Key.DisplayName);
                subNode.AddItem(itemNode);
                foreach (var payload in item)
                {
                    itemNode.AddPayload(payload.Payload as Payload);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I look in the debugger, I see a strongly typed tree.  Don't be afraid of anonymous types.  The `var` keyword is your friend (well, that and the debugger).

Comment: I plugged your code into my project and when looking at it with the debugger I'm seeing the hierarchy I'm looking for, but this generates anonymous types that I'm not familiar with traversing. My ultimate goal is to populate a TreeView control with this data so I need the data in a structure like the TreeItem class shown above. An example of how to put the data in the structure I need would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This gets me very close to what I need. Thanks for your time and effort in helping me out.