# Nested Array with C#

Tags: c#, linq

i have a table which has product category, product type, and product detail.
i want to create a nested array using LINQ query like if it has multiple categories like a burger, pizza etc.

[see table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr5tU.png)

suppose if a category is Pizza then there are 3 types of Pizzas: vegetable, meat, beef, and mixed. then there are different types like 6-inch pizza, 12-inch pizza.
I want output like this.

1 pizza :

```
  > > chicken:
        > > > 6 inch pizza
        > > > 12 inch pizza

  > > vegetable:
        > > > 6 inch pizza
        > > > 12 inch pizza
```

2 Burger :

```
   > > Fish:
       > > > Medium
       > > > large
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that did not work?

Comment: i have seen this piece of code  var grouped = from v in context.PizzaPizza
                          group v by new { VN = v.Category, VD = v.Type } into grp
                          orderby grp.Key.VN, grp.Key.VD
                          select new { VN_VD = grp.Key, Items = grp };
            return grouped; but unable to get desired result

Comment: That looks like JSON - I say 'looks like' because as posted it is not valid.  But I cant figure out what linq has to do with anything.

Comment: i am working on Web service. i have shared desired result. @New Contributor

Comment: Your category Pizza seems to have 4 types, not 3. Please don't use images to post data or code.

Comment: pizza can have multiple types .  sorry i am posting question first time i will take care of it next time

Comment: Read over @NewContributor's note.  You are showing invalid JSON.  There's no C# code and definitely no LINQ.  I can't follow.

Comment: @Flydog57 yes i know it is invalid just post as example. i am writing linq query to fetch data from table. therefore i am saying nested array

Comment: You don't need to "take care of it next time"; you can edit this post to make it more intelligible.  Take your table and format it into "code" so that it's text (that way you don't post a link to an image).  Show us what you are talking about.  Invalid JSON doesn't really tell us anything.  Once people can quickly understand you, they can more quickly respond.

Comment: @Flydog57 Modified my post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use linq .GroupBy
It should give you what you need

Comment: do i need to use multiple Group by ? actually i have 3 level . First Category then Type and Product

Comment: If you want to use multi-level group-by, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526410/convert-a-flat-list-to-a-multi-level-hierarchy/52527467#52527467

Comment: Something like .GroupBy(x => new {x.Category, x.Type})

Comment: @tncb how can show Group name ? like i have mention in example with every group i need to show its category and type

Comment: @Flydog57 it is use full but i need to show group name for each group e.g Pizza then meat

Comment: thanks @Flydog57 and tncb .i have got my desired result .i have used group by on both columns.