# C# Winforms: how to get value when a user select (mouse click) a point on chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

[image]

I want get `StaffId` on MessageBox when I click for example on David point chart (on Blue area of David as Image shows).

I mean `StaffId` of clicked employee's name.

Here is my series presentation..

```
var series = chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
series.XValueMember = "StaffId";
series.YValueMembers = "Total";
series.Name = "Employee";
```

and the Linq query I am using

```
var result = (from u in db.Transactions
              join st in db.Users on u.StaffId equals st.UserId
              group u by u.Users.FirstName into g
              select new
              {
                  StaffId = g.Key,
                  Total = g.Count() 
              }).ToList();

chart1.DataSource = result;     
chart1.DataBind();
chart1.Show();
```

I tried like this but not working

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Totally stop here .. ;)       
}
```

Comment: What is `chart1`? Is from a microsoft library? Is from a third party library?

Comment: ikerbera , sorry I forgot to attach Image. It is from Visual Studio chart controll

Comment: Can chart trigger an `OnClick` event? Can you add a handler for that event? If yes, what information is avaiable in the `args`?

Comment: @KarelFrajták what do you mean  chart trigger ? I have updated my question with an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MouseUp event:

```
private void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pointEndX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
    var pointEndY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
}
```

So the full code would be something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    class User
    {
        public string StaffId { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }

    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        var series = chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
        series.XValueMember = "StaffId";
        series.YValueMembers = "Total";
        series.Name = "Employee";

        var users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User(){StaffId = "John", Total = 70});
        users.Add(new User() { StaffId = "David", Total = 81 });
        users.Add(new User() { StaffId = "Sara", Total = 81 });

        chart1.DataSource = users;
        chart1.DataBind();
        chart1.Show();
    }

    private void chart1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pointEndX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);

        var list = (List<User>)chart1.DataSource;

        //round to the nearest whole number
        pointEndX = Math.Round(pointEndX, 0);

        //subtract 1 because bars start at 1 and List/Array are 0 indexed
        int index = ((int)pointEndX )- 1;

        if(index <0 || index>=list.Count)
            return;

        var user = list[index];
        MessageBox.Show(user.StaffId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you using `if (!annotating)` for?

Comment: Oops, should have got rid of that.  This is copied from my codebase where the user can add annotations to the chart (TextAnnotation, LineAnnotation etc) but they have to have turned on annotation mode.

Comment: @ThomasN Thank you for response but I want to get StaffId of David when I klick on David chart and Sara's StaffId when I click on Sara's chart part and so on as you see in Image . StaffId means UserId.  What I'am geting from your code is a value of X and Y.

Comment: What value do you get in pointEndX if you put a break point in your code after it and click on David bar?

Comment: Well, it depends where in the area I click, right now I get 2.283674....... I'am geting a value of X

Comment: Looks like the bars are 1,2,3 as far as the control is concerned?  So if you cast that to an `int` there should be a collection you can index either in the chart or in your local variable `result` (which would have to become a class level field). e.g. `result[((int)pointEndX)-1]`

Comment: @ThomasN where du I write this code result[((int)pointEndX)-1]  ???? I realy don't get it ..;) Variable result is inside button

Comment: I've updated to include a full example.  I created my own list because I don't have access to your database/classes.

Comment: @ThomasN thank you, but If I Exclude my database and use your hole code as it is, then   I get name, not Id.

Comment: @HelenTekie My code is just an example, you should take the MouseUp code only and paste it into your own code.  Then you need to cast chart1.DataSource to whatever your linq statement produces (debugger should tell you that).  I.e. it won't be a `List<User>` it will be a `List<SomethingElse>`

Comment: If I do as you Writing then I get error message like ... "failed to convert a system.Collections.Generic.List object [<> f_AnonymousType8'2 [System.String, System.int32]]] to the system.Collection.Generic.List [EmpReport.Users] type"

Comment: Ok so `select new` in your linq code is creating an AnonymousType.  Can you instead create a class yourself? e.g. `select new MyClass {StaffId = g.Key,Total = g.Count()}).ToList();`  That would get around that problem.  It would basically look the same as the `User` class I created.

Comment: @ThomasN very strange, I get name  then not Id.. ;)

Comment: @ThomasN if you look my result Queary , maybe there is something to change there

Comment: Yes you `group u by u.Users.FirstName` then assign it to `StaffId` in your linq.  I don't really know linq to sql that well.  Can you group by name AND StaffId since I'm guessing that's what you would want anyway.  Then store all 3 in your class.

Comment: @ThomasN , I want to show employee name in chart then I want to click on that specific employeename and get his/her Id and show Another information like details about this clicked employee. Offcourse if I change grouped by u.Users.StaffId, then I get StaffId even by u.Users.username then I get value username. But chart part do not show names of employee. It shows Id and username. But this is a litle progress ;) Maybe it's enough if I show username instead.

Comment: Good luck.  Maybe you can use the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns to select both StaffId and Username.