# D365 - Find duplicate records for composite keys using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to filter on `RetrieveAll` result received from `QueryExpression`in **D365**

Here is the code snippet:

```
private static List<IGrouping<string, Entity>> RetrieveDuplicates(IOrganizationService _crmService, DuplicateSearch duplicateSearch)
{
    QueryExpression query = GenerateQueryExpression(duplicateSearch.EntityLogicalName, duplicateSearch.DuplicatedColumnName, duplicateSearch.ColumnList.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("\n INFO: Finding duplicates is in progress ... \n");
    var results = _crmService.RetrieveAll(query)
                                    .OrderBy(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>(duplicateSearch.DuplicatedColumnName))
                                    .ThenByDescending(e => e.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("createdon"))
                                    .GroupBy(e => e.GetAttributeValue<string>(duplicateSearch.DuplicatedColumnName), e => e).ToList();

    WriteDuplicateRecordsInFile(results, duplicateSearch.EntityLogicalName);
    return results;
}
```

I'm thinking to pass `duplicateSearch.DuplicatedColumnName` as `List<string>` but do not know how I can set it in `GroupBy`.

But now, as per requirement, I want to `GroupBy` multiple key but don't know how can I do it.

Let me know if any other information is required.

> Note: I want to use here dynamics attributes which will be selected by
>   user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: @JSteward: No it is not, as I do not have fix column neither datatype. I've just came to know above code will throw error for int value.