# Linq idea on date calculation

Tags: linq

How to convert this query to linq?

```
Example: 
`select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, '2020-05-17 19:20:00' ), 0)`
```

```
Result: `'2020-05-17 19:00:00'`
```

Update question to more detail..

```
Example Input data:
**DateTimeColumn**
2020-05-17 11:29:12.1234
2020-05-17 19:20:00.2132
2020-05-17 19:30:00.2132
2020-05-17 22:34:22.2134
2020-05-18 11:01:01.1111

Query:
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DateTimeColumn ), 0) as NewTime, Count(*) as Count from Table group by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DateTimeColumn ), 0)

Result:

**NewTime**         **Count**
2020-05-17 11:00:00  1  
2020-05-17 19:00:00  2
2020-05-17 22:00:00  1
2020-05-18 11:00:00  1
```

Purpose: Need a linq query for group by hour, can't use `group by datetime.hour` due to it will merge hourly data with different date (example the 11 A.M for 17/5 and 18/5 are two different data, can't group together)

Comment: You need to group by day **and** by hour, here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Comment: Hi @colinD, this is 1 column only

Comment: You aren't showing a query, but in LINQ you can do date math and you can use `EF.Functions` for direct access to SQL date/time functions. What type of LINQ are you using (e.g. LINQ to SQL, EF 6, EF Core 2, EF Core 2.2, EF Core 3.x)?

Comment: Hi @NetMage, I am using Linq2SQL now. What you mean LINQ can do date mate?

Answer (score 0):

Given,

```
var baseDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
```

You can use it in LINQ to SQL such as:

```
var grouped = from r in db
              let hr = baseDate.AddHours(Math.Truncate((r.a_date-baseDate).TotalHours))
              group r by hr into rg
              select new {
                  Hour = rg.Key,
                  Count = rg.Count()
              };
```

Comment: Thank you @NetMage!! May I know what is a_date?

Comment: why need minus the baseDate? Can you explain more? sorry, I didnt get your concept.

Comment: @kchongHoh your example had a literal date in it, instead of referencing a field from a database. `a_date` just represents any date field in your database. You would need to update your question with real information to get a matching answer.

Comment: The `-basedate` is a translation of the `datediff(hour, 0, ` in your SQL. In SQL, the `0` represents a base date to compute from. Do you understand what the SQL does?

Comment: Thank for your reply. I just don't understand what your LINQ does.