# How to use multiple Group By in Entity Framework C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have an SQL query written for multiple group by

```
select COUNT(Count) as Count, City,State,ZipCode from ZipSearchHistories Group By City,State,ZipCode
```

Now I need to change this SQL query into Entity Framework. What I tried so far is

```
var result = await repository.GetAllAsync();
      
            var data = from m in result
                       group m by m.City, m.State,m.ZipCode into g
                       let Count = g.Count()
                       orderby Count descending
                       select new { Count= Count,City = m.City,State = m.State, ZipCode = m.ZipCode}
```

but it didn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: define "didn't work". did it throw an error? then share it. did it group your data differently from what you expected? then share what you expected and what happened.

Comment: Could this answer your query https://stackoverflow.com/a/847097/7299782

Comment: @FranzGleichmann It was saying incorrect syntax.

Comment: For LINQ, you need to "group by" using a type, for example `.GroupBy (m => new { m.City, m.State,m.ZipCode})`.  But when you ask a question, YOU SHOULD ALWAYS COPY/PASTE THE EXACT ERROR!,  For future reference :)

Comment: @BirazDahal then the logical step would've been to check in the manual _what_ the correct syntax might have been. googling for "linq group by syntax", for example, yielded [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) as first result.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of `ZipSearchHistories`. Every ZipSearchHistory in this sequence has at least a ZipCode, a State and a City.

Some of these ZipSearchHistories have the same values for {ZipCode, State, City}. You want to count for every combination of {ZipCode, State, City} the number of ZipSearchHistories that have this combination.

You are right, for this you'll need [one of the overloads of Queryable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1). I most often use the overload that has a parameter resultSelector. With this parameter you can specify the output per group.

```
var result = dbContext.ZipSearchHistories(

    // parameter keySelector: make groups with same values for {ZipCode, State, City}
    zipSearchHistory => new
    {
        ZipCode = zipSearchHistory.ZipCode, 
        State = zipSearchHistory.State,
        City = zipSearchHistory.City,
    },

    // parameter resultSelector: for every key {ZipCode, State, City},
    // and all ZipSearchHistories that have this {ZipCode, State, City} make one new:
    (key, zipSearchHistoriesWithThisKey) => new
    {
        ZipCode = key.ZipCode, 
        State = key.State,
        City = key.City,
        Count = zipSearchHistoriesWithThisKey.Count(),
    })
```

In words: make groups of ZipSearchHistories, that have the same value for {ZipCode, State, City}. From every group (where all elements have this {ZipCode, State, City}) make one new object, that has these {ZipCode, State, City} and the number of elements in the group.