# Entity Framework average, group by query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to convert a SQL query to Linq for an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    E.Surname, E.Name, E.Patronymic, AVG(CAST(IEEResult1 AS FLOAT))
FROM
    IEEResults AS I
JOIN
    Enrollee AS E ON E.Id = I.EnrolleeId
GROUP BY 
    I.EnrolleeId, E.Surname, E.Name, E.Patronymic
ORDER BY 
    AVG(CAST(IEEResult1 AS FLOAT)) DESC;
```

This is the answer. Thank you [afrazier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320333/afrazier) very much!

```
 var result = db.IEEResults
    .Join(db.Enrollees, r => r.EnrolleeId, e => e.Id, (r, e) => new { e.Id, e.Surname, e.Name, e.Patronymic, r.IEEResult1 })
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.Id, a.Surname, a.Name, a.Patronymic })
    .Select(gr => new IEEResultsDTO
    {
        Id = gr.Key.Id,
        Surname = gr.Key.Surname,
        Name = gr.Key.Name,
        Patronymic = gr.Key.Patronymic,
        AvgResult = gr.Average(a => a.IEEResult1)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.AvgResult)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList().AsEnumerable();
            return View(result);
```

Comment: are you really using link to sql (your tag)? or are you using EF ? What version?

Comment: EF 6, I put linq-to-sql by mistake

Comment: and what exactly is "not working" is it your group by?  check --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns

Comment: You have `group a by a.Id into gr` which means `gr.Key` and `a.Id` are the same - is `a.Id` a class? Otherwise, you can't reference `gr.Key.Surname` unless `a.Id.Surname` is valid. Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Enrollee does not contain the definition of IEEResult1 :) Still fighting with Average function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exception message you get.

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove the original issue and incorporate the answer from a posted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put `IEEResult1` into your group since you want to operate on the collection of those items.  I'm not very good with the query syntax, but this should be a working query for the lambda syntax.

```
var result = db.IEEResults
    .Join(db.Enrollees, r => r.EnrolleeId, e => e.Id, (r, e) => new { e.Id, e.Surname, e.Name, e.Patronymic, r.IEEResult1 })
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.Id, a.Surname, a.Name, a.Patronymic })
    .Select(gr => new {
        gr.Key.Id, gr.Key.Surname, gr.Key.Name, gr.Key.Patronymic,
        AvgResult => gr.Average(a => a.IEEResult1)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.AvgResult)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are very good in query syntax!