# C# Linq Grouping in one query by different conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I know that if I need to group in Linq I do this:

```
var results = from p in persons
              group p by p.PersonID into g
```

and if I need to group using another field/criteria, I do this:

```
var results2 = from p in persons
              group p by p.PersonName into g
```

but this means traversing the list I have twice. Is there anyway to do both grouping in one statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

Grouped by key is person_id and person_name:

```
var results = from p in persons
              group p by new { p.PersonID , p.PersonName } into g
```

Comment: This will group by both columns, what I need is to group by two different criteria, to get the count of each separately