# SQL - Select unique multiple columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to select from a table that contains some duplicate rows like the one below:

| OS | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| A | 10 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 10 |

I am trying to remove duplicates from both columns to get only unique values. It doesn´t matter which value will be at which OS. It should get something like this:

| OS | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 10 |

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group By Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I Couldn´t get the result table I was expecting. I was expecting a table like in my question.

Answer (score 0):

create table DemoTable (os char(1), value smallint)

insert into demotable values ('A', 5), ('A', 10), ('B', 5), ('B', 10)
declare @i int =1 
DECLARE @tempTable table (rowid int, os char(1), value smallint)

while @i<3 --this can be replaced with maximum 
begin 
insert into @tempTable (rowid, os, value)
values (@i, (select OS from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by os) rowid,OS FROM DemoTable GROUP BY OS) x where rowid = @i),
(select value from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value) rowid, value FROM DemoTable GROUP BY value) x where rowid = @i))

set @i = @i + 1
end

select os, value from  @tempTable

Answer (score 0):

> I am try solve this question, Please check my answer

```
SELECT * from test  group by os_1 ;
```

[image]

> I just changed column name and table name ,you can change to your column and table name .

Answer (score -1):

You can group by the first column and get the max value of the second:

```sql
SELECT OS, MAX(Value)
FROM oss 
GROUP BY OS
```

Check this [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXQd3jATF2JoP7WzNKYR2w/0).

Comment: Hi Joaquin. I want to get one of each value, not the max(value).

Comment: then it looks like you'd probably have to use two tables: unique OS and unique Value